# Why does this use of using declaration compile?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/aTxbqP) with all 3 major compilers without any problems (MSVC has a bug with accepting of invalid similar code, but that is unrelated to my question):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Z{
    struct Na{
        struct Batman{
            int x=47;
        };
    };
}

int main(){
   using Na = Z::Na;
   return Na::Na::Na::Na::Na::Na::Na::Batman{}.x;
}
```

Is there any logic behind this, or is it just a weird edge case that ends up being legal when applying rules made for "normal" uses?

If my confusion is not clear: I would expect the weird line to be parsed either as

- many nested namespaces, e.g. `std::std::std` and rejected
- a reference to a constructor (`Na::Na`) and then rejected when the following `::Na` is encountered

Comment: I want to upvote a second time for the example code :) Though `x` should be 42 ;)

Comment: fwiw, I never saw Batman and any of those three compilers in the same room at the same time

Comment: @Bathsheba It's unfortunate for sure. fwiw I'm pretty sure this was down-voted *after* the question was hammered. Maybe someone DVed because of lack of research, but how the OP would have found the target without knowing the specific term is beyond me.

Comment: I myself would have gone for a struct field named `HeyHey` but maybe I'm from a different era of pop culture ...

Comment: @Bathsheba That would mean that no one could ask [tag:language-lawyer] questions any more, so maybe not a terrible idea ... ;)

Comment: holy injected class name Batman!