# Is A::B::B::B::B...B::f() right ? Why could i do that?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

I don't know how to explain this:

```cpp
namespace A
{
struct B
{
  static void  f()
  {
  }
};
}

int  main()
{
  A::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::f();
}
```

Why could i do :

```cpp
A::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::f();
```

I don't understand it why it's happening.

Comment: Probably want the `language-lawyer` tag.  Looks like you've found a C++ easter egg.

Comment: another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077931/why-does-this-use-of-using-declaration-compile

Comment: hard to find such dupes, I was only able to find it because I remembered it had something to do with batman :)

Comment: That's fun. https://godbolt.org/z/hPfaoj

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, I preferred that form of the question ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is due to [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

inside class B, `B` refers to class `B`, as `B::B`.

so `A::B::B` refers to class `B`. and so on.