# Using decltype in a nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, decltype, name-lookup, qualified-name

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
    struct A
    {
        static int n;
    };
    
    A A;
}

int N::A::n = 10;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << N::A::n << '\n';
    std::cout << N::decltype( N::A )::n << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles successfully using gcc 8.3 at for example [www.ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com).

However if to run this program using MS VS 2019 then the compiler issues an error relative to the record `decltype( N::A )` in the nested-name-specifier. If to remove preceding name `N::` then the program compiles successfully.

Is it a bug of the MS VS compiler or is the nested-name-specifier written incorrectly?

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077931/why-does-this-use-of-using-declaration-compile (Note that the question mentions MSVC accepting "similar but different" invalid code, which is rather the oposite of situation here, also OP doesnt mention what code that is.)

Comment: Also - why would you do this? I don't get the reasoning behind `N::decltype( N::A )::n`. `decltype( N::A )` already resolves to `N::A`, so I don't understand what prefixing it with `N::` would accomplish (GCC is definitely wrong to accept this - Clang also rejects this code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *decltype-specifier* can never appear except at the beginning of a *nested-name-specifier*.  After all, it designates a specific type, and no name lookup is necessary *afterwards* to interpret it.  GCC is **wrong** to accept the code: by experimentation, it seems to just ignore any preceding components after checking that they exist.